# Using ComponentDidMount to load data before page renders - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `ComponentDidMount` to call data from my database and render page when data is ready. However, i have noticed the speed of my application has reduced when navigating since i have to wait for the data.

This is happening when i have large data in the database i am retrieving.  My question is, is there any way of optimizing this, or i just have to render page before data loads ?

**Component.JS**

```
componentDidMount()
     {
        this.fetchAllItems();           
     } 

 fetchAllItems(){
        return this.fetchPost().then(([response,json]) => {
         console.log('here now ',response);
         console.log(localStorage.getItem('user_token'))
           if(response.status === 200)
           {   

           }
        })
     }



     fetchPost(){
        const URL = 'http://localhost:8000/api/';
        return fetch(URL, {method:'GET',headers:new Headers ({
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              })})
        .then(response => Promise.all([response, response.json()]));
     }
```

Comment: It does not wait for your data to arrive (at least [not yet](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/11/27/react-16-roadmap.html#react-16x-mid-2019-the-one-with-suspense-for-data-fetching)), the fetch call is async

Comment: I would go with adding spinner/loading indicator for the first page load, add list of data to localStorage and on then on page refresh load data from localStorage and update state in background with some sort of line-progress bar.

Comment: Read this https://hackernoon.com/lazy-loading-and-preloading-components-in-react-16-6-804de091c82d

Comment: reducing speed of your application can be caused by something else, this code you provided here , give me nothing much about your navigation.
but you can use Next.js And fetch your data even before ComponentDidMount and use that data as props with the help of Next.js.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to make call to API asynchronously, after it's done, just update your response data to `state`. No need to wait your page is finished loading or not, react will render by following changes of state value.

```js
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class MovieList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    movies: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost/movies`)
      .then(res => {
        const movies = res.data;
        this.setState({ movies: movies });
      })
  }

  render() {
    const {
       movies
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
          <ul>
          { movies.map(movie => <li>{movie.name}</li>)}
          </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This really has nothing to do with what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method? This method accepts nextProps (new or upcoming props) and nextState (new or upcoming State) parameters. You can compare your next props and state (state preferably in your case) to determine if your component should re-render or not. Fewer re-renders equals to better speed and optimization. that means your pages will load faster. The `shouldComponentUpdate` method returns a boolean to determine if a page should re-render or not. Read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate). Also, Here's an example:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: true,
      countOfClicks: 0
    };
    this.pickRandom = this.pickRandom.bind(this);
  }

  pickRandom() {
    this.setState({
      value: Math.random() > 0.5, // randomly picks true or false
      countOfClicks: this.state.countOfClicks + 1
    });
  }

  // comment out the below to re-render on every click
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return this.state.value != nextState.value;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        shouldComponentUpdate demo 
        <p><b>{this.state.value.toString()}</b></p>
        <p>Count of clicks: <b>{this.state.countOfClicks}</b></p>
        <button onClick={this.pickRandom}>
          Click to randomly select: true or false
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case all the optimization must be done in the backend.

But if there is something that can be done in React is using Should Component Update as previous comment mentioned.